# Changing devise_invitable mailer subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer, rails-i18n, devise-invitable

on default, the subject for invitation mail is

```
  mailer:
      invitation_instructions:
        subject: 'Invitation instructions'
```

I'd like to change it to

```
subject: '%{invited_by} has invited you!'
```

but this requires to have invited_by variable accessible to the translate method for i18n.

How can I have this variable accessible/declared without changing default behavior too much?

Comment: sorry to disturb, but it looks like you don't think that my answer worth your bounty and I'm a little bit curious about it.
Do you think the answer is wrong, or it's not detailed enough, or something?

Comment: Actually, I upvoted it, and I am now checking to see that it works as intended.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Devise default mailer won't work for you, but it's quite easy to set up a custom mailer and define there your own subject_for helper:

```rb
# in config/initializers/devise.rb:
...
config.mailer = "CustomDeviseMailer"
...
```

```rb
# in app/mailers/custom_devise_mailer.rb:

class CustomDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  protected

  def subject_for(key)
    return super  unless key.to_s == 'invitation_instructions'

    I18n.t('devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.subject', 
      :invited_by => resource.invited_by.try(:full_name) || 'Someone')
  end
end
```

Comment: at some point they switched it from a string to a symbol so you may need to use  return super  unless key == :invitation_instructions

Comment: Also, I think this answer deserves to be marked as "correct", @NickGinanto